# How to get the facebook's user's connection in my application?

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, smartphone

My device has the Facebook application and if the user has already identified himself through Facebook app, I would like that it won't be done through my app a second time (only rights demand). 
I searched on the web without success and the examples with Facebook SDK always ask an idendification.

I know that is possible under iOs. Is it under Android ? And if yes, how can I manage that ?

Thanks.

(Thanks ZouZou to have translate)

Comment: Salut tu devrais écrire en anglais pour qu'un maximum de personnes puissent te répondre :)

Comment: Ok stack-overflow time to integrate with Google translator....

Comment: It is only possible if the current session is authenticated.. If you have two separate user sessions it will not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, this question is outdated.

Indeed, in the version 3 of the facebook SDK it's efficiently manage.

Just follow scrupulously the "How to" :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Have fun.